# Call function on child component after emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to create a custom button component with a spinner, it works fine - disables the button and shows a spinner when clicked but I'm having trouble resetting the button's state when whatever is "loading" is finished.

My current code is as follows:

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <custom-button @button-click="requestAPI" :disabled="canRequestAPI">
    Request API
  </custom-button>
</template>
<script>
  methods: {
    async requestAPI(){
      // Request API here
    }
</script>
```

CustomButton.vue

```
<template>
  <button :disabled="disabled || loading" @click="processClick" :loading="loading">
    <img src="/loader.svg" />
    <span class="buttonContent">
        <slot />
    </span>
  </button>
</template>
<script>
   props: ["disabled"],
   data() {
     return: {
       loading: false,
     }
   },
   methods: {
     processClick(){
       this.$emit('button-click');
       this.loading = true;
     }
   }
 </script>
```

The spinner shows and the API is requested but I can't work out how to stop the spinner in a good way. I could create a prop to watch and set loading to false but I'd like to be able to use this custom button several without having to add lots of different variables.

Ideally i'd be able to do something like:

Parent.vue

```
<script>
  methods: {
    async requestAPI(e){
      // Request API here
      e.stopLoading();
    }
</script>
```

CustomButton.vue

```
<script>
   methods: {
     stopLoading(){
       this.loading = false;
     }
   }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, Just emitted the stopLoading function to the parent and called that.

Parent.vue

```
<script>
  methods: {
    async requestAPI(stopLoading){
      // Request API here
      stopLoading();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Child.vue

```
methods: {
   processClick(){
     this.$emit('button-click', () => this.stopLoading());
     this.loading = true;
   },
   stopLoading(){
     this.loading = false;
   }
}
```